# Will Lightning Process Builder replace Trigger dispatching logic?

Tags: trigger, workflow, isv, design-patterns, process-builder

I am not asking if we app developer can finally replace code with point-n-click tools.

But I am asking if we will still need Trigger logic that handles modified record and dispatches them to Apex code.

Lightning Process builder seems to become a way better tool for this dispatching and @InvocableActions would allow for code reuse much better than code in Trigger Handler Delegate classes.

Is this something we (ISV) app developers should look at or is this just a neat new replacement of the old Workflow rules and Flow?

Answer (score 5):

It will eventually replace workflow. Think of it like workflow 2.0. Long way off yet. It's the primary way to dispatch flows replacing flow triggers if you have seen that one. As for replacing a apex trigger framework entirely. Possibly over time, there are still glaring holes like the ability to work across the full range of DML events; delete as one example. Love your thinking though!

Answer (score 1):

I also see the appeal of this type of architecture. Using a single framework to contain all of your logic would be much simpler than having logic separated into workflows and triggers where you have to sort out the complex relationships between them.

One fundamental problem I see with the process builder is that it works on single records rather than the entire batch, while proper trigger code needs to look at all of the records in the execution context and operate in bulk.

It looks like at this point processes are just an improved version of workflows, but hopefully they are moving towards having a better union of clicks and code.

Comment: There has been progress made on the bulkification end with process builder:  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_bulkification.htm